# appdelegate error at @interface: "expected identifier or {" and "Parse issue: Missing @end"

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, uiapplicationdelegate

I'm getting errors for the appdelegate.h: "expected identifier or {" and "Parse issue: Missing @end".

I've tried everything I can think of to fix this. I've checked the headers and #imports. I've moved all the classes into a new project thinking there was something wrong in the build settings. I even reinstalled Xcode to no avail. Here's the app delegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    MainViewController *viewController;
    NSMutableArray *savedBookmarksArray;
}

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet MainViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *savedBookmarksArray;

@end
```

Every class that references the app delegate said the file could not be found. The .m is included in the Compile Sources. Anyone know how to fix this?

main.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

MainViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "DDWebView.h"

@class AboutTableViewController;

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {


}

@end
```

Comment: is the delegate imported in main.m ?

Comment: What is the contents of `MainViewController.h`, the error could just as well be there.

Comment: Do you have a blank line after `@end` ? Seriously, i remember that was as issue for me one day.

Comment: I did have a line after @end. Removed it but that didn't fix it.

Comment: did you try to clean and rebuild the project ? relaunch the xcode ?

Comment: It might be the case that a *different* file is missing "@end" but it reports the error for the app delegate.

Comment: Provide the code for `MainViewController.h `.

Comment: I added the main.m and MainViewController.h

Comment: if you replace `#import "MainViewController.h"` with `@class MainViewController` , will that solve the problem ?

Comment: @Malek_Jundi no, I get the error "Receiver 'MainViewController' for class message is a forward declaration"

Comment: try put the `#import "MainViewController.h"` in .m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue. I had an import as `#import "AppDelegate"` instead of `#import "AppDelegate.h"` in one of my other headers.

Thanks for all your help guys!
..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but it turned out that i accidentally declared the @interface inside the .m file and that screwed around with it. Once i removed it from the .m file it worked.